# Extracting just some desired text

Tags: java, regex

I have a URL as a `String`:

```
"http://www.example.com/ex.now#ONEhttp://www.example.com/ex.now#TWO"
```

I want the result to be:

> ONE
>
> TWO

I have to to use `replaceAll` and `split` but I still don't get it right.

Here is part of what I have tried to do:

```
String[] outArray = resultOut.split("#");
String res="";

for (String str : outArray) 
{
    res +=str;
}

System.out.println(res);
```

It gives:

> nullhttp://www.example.com/ex.nowONE
>
> http://www.example.com/ex.nowTWO

Comment: `"... but I still don't get it right. Please help put me through."` -- sure, but please first show us what you've tried and tell us why/how it isn't working. Else, how will we know what you are confused about? We're not here to do your work/homework for you, but we're more than happy to help you with your work, so why not show us the evidence of your efforts and ask your specific questions?

Comment: This is definitely in java, not javascript? Can you show the code you currently have?

Comment: @popnoodles: replaceAll and split are common Java methods that are often used to change text in Strings or extract tokens from Strings via regular expressions, so I'm pretty sure that this is Java, but I agree that arewa needs to show us the fruits of his labors. Otherwise it looks little more than a blatant beg for code.

Comment: Please I have added part of my attempts. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to select part of a String and you're familiar with regular expressions, look into the java.util.regex.Pattern and java.util.regex.Matcher class documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I would replace first, using something like this:

```
^[^#]+#
```

This will take in your original string, and gives `ONEhttp://www.example.com/ex.now#TWO` after being replaced with "", which you can then split on a regex for the link:

```
String resultOut = "http://www.example.com/ex.now#ONEhttp://www.example.com/ex.now#TWO";
String outString = resultOut.replaceAll("^[^#]+#", "");
String[] outArray = outString.split("http[^#]+#");
String res="";

for (String str : outArray) 
{
    res += "{" + str + "}";
}

System.out.println(res);
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rhfFuZ)

Comment: Thank you for this, but I realized that if I have those target texts as not capital-all-through, i.e. if "ONE" is changed to "One" and "TWO" is changed to "Two" then the result will be {OTwo} instead of {One} [Two}. Please help further, I really appreciate. Thanks